# Detect first page load with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

I need to detect the first time a page loads in jQuery so that I can perform some actions only when the page loads the first time a user navigates to that page. Similar to server side code page.ispostbasck. I have tested $(document).ready and it fires every time the page loads so this will not provide what I need. I have also tried the jQuery Load function - it also fires every page load. So by page load an example is that I have an HTML input tag on the page of type button and it does not fire a postback (like an asp.net button) but it does reload the page and fires  $(document).ready

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use cookies dude.

Answer (score 19):

You will have to use cookie to store first load information:

```
if (! $.cookie("cookieName")){
   // do your stuff

   // set cookie now
   $.cookie("cookieName", "firstSet", {"expires" : 7})
}
```

*Note: Above example uses [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).*

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this problem and this is how I handled it. Keep track of the first time the page loads by using a variable `initialLoad`:

```
var initialLoad = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    ...
    ... 

    initialLoad = false;

});
```

Then in other functions, you can do this:

```
if (initialLoad) {
    //Do work that is done when the page was first refreshed/loaded.
} else {
    //Do work when it's not the initial load.
}
```

This works well for me. If the user is already on the page and some jQuery functions run, I now know if that user just loaded the page or if they were already on the page.

Comment: "I have tested $(document).ready and it fires every time the page loads so this will not provide what I need." - clearly not what he asked for

Answer (score 8):

An event doesn't exist that fires only when the page is loaded for the first time.

You should use [jQuery's `.ready()` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), and then persist the fact that you've handled a first time page load using your method of choice (i.e. cookie, session variable, local storage, etc.).

**Note:** This method will never be fool proof unless you can store this information at the user level in a DB. Otherwise, as soon as the user clears their cookies, or whatever method you choose, the "first time loaded" code will fire again.

Comment: What he said.  Jquery (and javascript in general) have no inherent persistence between page loads.

Answer (score -3):

The easy solution is to use jQuery ‘Once’ plugin

```
$(element).once('class-name', function() {
  // your javascript code
});
```