# how to check if page is loaded for the first time using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the page is being loaded for the first time, and if it is then display the filter. If I put showFiltermenu() in the pageLoad function then it will show every time the page is loaded but I just want it display the first time. I tried using `Page.IsPostBack` but that doesn't display the filter.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFiltermenu() {
            $("#filtermenuDrop").toggle('fold', {}, 500);
        }
        function closefiltermenu() {
            $("#filtermenuDrop").toggle('fold', {}, 500);
        }

function pageLoad() {
        $("input[rel^='datepicker']").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: "c-50:c+50",
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: "both",
            firstDay: 1,
            buttonImage: "../images/icons/buttons/basic1-049-small.png"
        });
        <% if (Page.IsPostBack)
           { %>
                showFiltermenu();
        <% } %>

        ShadowboxInit();

    }
```

Comment: You can use cookies.

Comment: You are asking for cookies.

Comment: you can set a cookie or use localstorage

Comment: look at this link ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485099/detect-first-page-load-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their answers but there was just a simple mistake in my question. I forgot the `!` in the if statement. This now works to check if the page is loaded for the first time.

```
<% if (!Page.IsPostBack)
           { %>
                showFiltermenu();
        <% } %>
```

Comment: how can you do this in php?

Answer (score 20):

with `localStorage` you can save values like this:

```
var firstTime = localStorage.getItem("first_time");
if(!firstTime) {
    // first time loaded!
    localStorage.setItem("first_time","1");
}
```

no jQuery, no plugins, just pure, beautiful and fast HTML5 API

Comment: Does this works now ? what will be the challenges if we use this functionality

Comment: That would not work if the same user enters with different devices though

Comment: This will not work, if the same user opens the website in different browsers. Because Local storage is specific to browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try with cookie.
The cookie are very usefull for this kind of thing.
First of all let's see if the browser know cookie:

```
if(document.cookie)
{document.cookie="Name=Value";
}

else{
alert("perhaps you must change browser.Something in this page can't  load.")
}
```

Remember,cookie return always a string,if you write down on the console

```
 document.cookie
```

Set a cookie is simple.You can set a lot of cookie.But if you delete the cookies,the browser things that you are visiting the website for the first time.
To check if a cookie is set you can do this:

```
 if(document.cookie.search="value")
 {//code that you want to execute if the page is visited yet}
```

Comment: this makes the filter display every time the page is loaded. I only want the first time the page is loaded.