# how to load confetti only one time for a user

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to load the confetti at a specific time.  After that time is passed or once the confetti is loaded for a user, I don't want it to be seen again for that user when he refreshes the page or changes the page.

I used this code to run the confetty

```
<script src="https://www.wpromotions.eu/confetti.min.js"></script>
<script>confetti.start()</script>
<script>setTimeout(function(){confetti.stop();},6000)</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check if page is loaded for the first time using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605570/how-to-check-if-page-is-loaded-for-the-first-time-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the [Local Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can save values like this:

```
let firstTime = localStorage.getItem("confetti_loaded");

if (firstTime != 'yes') {
   // first time loaded!
   localStorage.setItem("confetti_loaded","yes");
   confetti.start()
}
```

Now this will load your confetti.min.js only 1 time then after no matter how many times user refresh the page if you wants to load js again simply remove the value that is store in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("confetti_loaded","");
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked
But <script>setTimeout(function(){confetti.stop();},6000)</script> This function is not working when I used this code. Confetti is not stopping now unless the value is lessthan 999. if I set timeout to more than 1000, confetti is not stopping

Could you please help with this?

Comment: I used <script>setTimeout(function(){confetti.remove();},6000)</script>
And it is working now

Thanks for the code...